# requestAlwaysAuthorization not showing permission alert

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I'm trying to use some fancy iBeacons without success, kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined all time. 
According to other questions it's a requirement to add those keys to info.plist (some questions says one, other says both). According to an article for iBeacons I need the Always option.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Nothing to say</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Permiso para acceder siempre</string>
```

At viewDidAppear:

```
self.locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locManager.delegate = self;
[self.locManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
NSUUID* region1UUID = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@""]; //ibeacon real UUID between "". Checked it's not nil.

self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]
                                initWithProximityUUID:proximityUUID
                                identifier:@"myCoolString"];

self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = NO;
[self.locManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
[self.locManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

Icon didn't appear at Settings/Privacy/Location until it was executed one of the two last methods. The Alert View to approve permissions never appears.
If I perform a manual change at Location Settings and check it it will change status but at a few moments later Location at Settings will delete "Always" status for my app and will leave it blank again. Later I check with no luck

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
```

Any ideas what is missing or wrong? Thank you

Comment: Check under privacy -> Location Services and make sure it isn't disabled for your app.  Once it is explicitly disabled the user won't be prompted.  Try deleting your app from the device and re-installing it

Comment: I've tried reinstalling several times. The process is when dialog doesn't appears in the app, I go to settings/privacy/location and check as "Always", after a few seconds it goes to full purple icon. Then I go to home, back to settings app and voilà, my app is still there but instead of "always" is blank again

Comment: Sounds like something is messed up with your device.  Do you have another device you can test on?  Or the simulator?

Comment: I have tested it in my phone and ipad, and it's the same behaviour in both.
Tried also this scenario: Device connected. Set "Always" option at settings, run the app and then it dissapears from settings.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm trying to find out if the documentation explains that the permission request is not shown if the location permission is explicitly not allowed for a given app or if this has changed since 2014

Comment: For me? I was testing it on my iPhone 11 - iOS 15.5, did everything right. I just had to reset the iPhone's privacy and network settings.

Answer (score 50):

For iOS 11 developers, you should take a look at this post: [Location Services not working in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424092/location-services-not-working-in-ios-11).

---

TL;DR: you need ALL THREE location keys in the Info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>...</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>...</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>...</string>
```

Along with `InfoPlist.strings` translations in case of multilingual apps.

Comment: You need to add these values to the root of Info.plist. The values are strings that will be presented to the user in an alert. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization.

Answer (score 20):

Had exactly the same problem.
It turned out that in my case the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` was required in my `InfoPlist.strings` localization files as well. Having `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in `Info.plist` wasn't enough...

Comment: I would add, also check if you have a `Info-Debug.plist`, etc. as I had put the string in my main `Info.plist` file but forgot to copy it over to the other. So in the simulator everything was silently failing much to my consternation.

Comment: where did you find such list (InfoPlist)? I can't find it

Answer (score 19):

I have noticed that if your instance of CLLocationManager is destroyed before the alert shows, you will never see the alert.
In my case I was creating a local variable of the location manager in the AppDelegate to ask for permission.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Changing the local variable to an instance variable made the alert to display:

```
@interface AppDelegate () {
    CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
}
@end

_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Comment: This was the problem for me also. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I got a similar problem recently with IOS 11 when I tried to use

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

The solution for me was to add  all the 4 permissions in `Info.plist` to get the alert:

- `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description`
- `Privacy - Location Usage Description`
- `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description`
- `Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description`

Answer (score 7):

Just add this lines to your .plist file

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Optional message</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to Start Updating Location (have helped for me)

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 3):

For ios 11 Its important to add below mention new permission which is

> NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription

along with the old permission which is

> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

to fix the requestAlwaysAuthorization not showing permission alert.

Answer (score 3):

Hardware-dependent System Issue?

iOS 13.1.3, iPhone 7 (model ID "iPhone9,1")

Seems like system Settings->Privacy->Location in some way cache permissions even after app deletion (at least, during the same iOS session and for specified configuration).

If 'allow once' is pressed and user deletes and reinstalls and runs the app again, didChangeAuthorizationStatus(_:) sends initial status .denied. (And therefore, according to CLLocationManager logic it does not show prompt alert after requestAlwaysAuthorization()).
This .denied status was the root of the evil in this case.

If user folds the app between initial didChangeAuthorizationStatus(*:) and requestAlwaysAuthorization(), this causes next update of didChangeAuthorizationStatus(*:) with status other than .denied and prompt alert will be shown.

iOS 13.1.3, iPhone 7 (model ID "iPhone9,3") - issue does not reproduce. (initial status received is .notDetermined)

iOS 13.1.2  iPhone 8 - all ok, same as above

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, used workaround with timer/timeout for this particular case.

Comment: Our testers are observing a similar issue. iOS 13.2.2, when they keep deleting and reinstalling from Test Flight on iPhone 7 and 8, they occasionally run into scenarios where the app gets initial permission as .denied but then if you go to Settings, it shows While in Use. Prompt for location is never showed in this scenario and once you restart the app, it gets permissions as while in use or whatever was selected in the previous install. Seems like schedules some background task or something and takes time to clear out permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Found, documented at forums and tested it's an Objective-C iOS 8 related bug.
Same code written in Swift just works. Working swift code, delegate is call.

Add Core Location framework to 
Project Settings / Targets / Capabilities / Background Modes set "Location Updates" and "Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories"
Add key at Info.plist NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

```
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {

var locManager: CLLocationManager?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locManager = CLLocationManager();
    self.locManager!.delegate = self;
    if (!CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        println("Location services are not enabled");
    }
    self.locManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
    self.locManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
    let uuidString = ""  // My ibeacon string there
    let beaconIdentifier = "myCompany"
    let beaconUUID:NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)
    let beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID,
        identifier: beaconIdentifier)
    self.locManager!.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
    self.locManager!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
    self.locManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Dialog appears OK

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the keys to the correct Info.plist file. Don't forget there's one for your App and one for AppTest.

Comment: this was my problem. Thanks! :P

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.X Latest** code easily usage

```
import CoreLocation

 public var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}



    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let altitudeG = locations.last?.altitude
        let longitudeG = locations.last?.coordinate.longitude
        let latitudeG = locations.last?.coordinate.latitude

print("\(altitudeG) \(longitudeG) \(latitudeG)")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied this tutorial ...

http://willd.me/posts/getting-started-with-ibeacon-a-swift-tutorial

It didn't work out the box, although the fix was very simple, don't declare

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

But move it into the class as variable

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

And it works!!

Answer (score 0):

It will show a prompt when the location permission for your app isn't set and once when 'in use' location permission for your app is set, subsequent calls do not show (and I don't think there is any API feedback that the call was swallowed).

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization):

> Discussion When the current authorization status is  notDetermined ,
>   this method runs asynchronously and prompts the user to grant
>   permission to the app to use location services. The user prompt
>   contains the text from the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key in
>   your app’s Info.plist file, and the presence of that key is required
>   when calling this method. After the status is determined, the location
>   manager delivers the results to the delegate’s 
>   locationManager(*:didChangeAuthorization:)  method. If the current
>   authorization status is anything other than notDetermined, this method
>   does nothing and does not call the
>   locationManager(*:didChangeAuthorization:) method, with one exception.
>   If your app has never requested always authorization and its current
>   authorization status is  authorizedWhenInUse , you may call this
>   method one time to try and change your app's authorization status to 
>   authorizedAlways .

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Reference link](https://mackuba.eu/2017/07/13/changes-to-location-tracking-in-ios-11/)

It has described all the changes regarding iOS 11. Your issue is also seems to be one among the cases it described. It might give you an idea what changes you need to make in your code to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me on iOS 13, I had to reset the Simulator to trigger the permission prompt again.

Answer (score 0):

To add to that: be sure you have added the array UIBackgroundModes to your .plist and inserted the "location" value.

Apple will not tell you it is missing and give you WhenInUse instead.

So in summary:

- Tell the system about your background modes through .plist (Required background modes > App registers for location updates)
- Tell the location manager you want to receive updates in the background (self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;)
- Ask for permission from the user from instance variable
  ([self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization])
- Provide valid texts for this request (info.plist contains: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription)

Answer (score -1):

recently, IOS 13, * save result request permission after user reinstall app