# Unable to get the permission prompt from CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, core-location

Here is my code from a ViewController implementing CLLocationManagerDelegate:

```
func startLocationManager() {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters


    println("I'm called")


    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    // locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    println(status.rawValue) // This print 0 which stands for kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined

    println(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) // true
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("nobody call me ever, and I'm sad")
}
```

For some reason, I never get the prompt / alter to autorise location updates. I have tried on my device iOS 8.1 and the simulartor. I followed the advices found here: [requestAlwaysAuthorization not showing permission alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005122/requestalwaysauthorization-not-showing-permission-alert) : 
"Add Core Location framework to Project Settings / Targets / Capabilities / Background Modes set "Location Updates" and "Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories" Add key at Info.plist NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription".

I have also tried to clean up and rebuild, nothing change. I feel clueless.

**EDIT**: This question seems related: [iOS: App is not asking user's permission while installing the app. getting kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined every time - Objective-c & Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664928/ios-core-location-is-not-asking-users-permission-while-installing-the-app-get) but the selected answer and its article doesn't expose anything new

Comment: Did you set string for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your app’s `Info.plist` file. If you don't, you won't see permission alert.

Comment: Yes I set a dummy string (and tried with it empty at the beginning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CLLocationManager` object is local object and thus will be deallocated immediately after it falls out of scope. Make it a class property and then asynchronous processes like requesting authorization and determining the location will have a chance to run.