# My app only asks for push-notifications permission but not for location. How can I fix that?

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, push-notification, cllocationmanager

In my app I have both of these lines:

```
manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in})
```

But when loaded, my application only requests permission for notifications. My app wouldn't work without the user giving permission to use its location. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [requestAlwaysAuthorization not showing permission alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005122/requestalwaysauthorization-not-showing-permission-alert)

Answer (score 0):

I can do assumption that you already grant permission or denied it. To verify it try to run this code:

```
let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
```

And detect status of the `CLLocationManager` now you will know what kind of state it is.

If state is  `notDetermined` ask for the permission in [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/22/2/requesting-location-core-location) way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key is present and has a string value in your Info.plist, otherwise location permission dialog wont appear