# how to show in settings only never / Always location permission and hide While using the App?

Tags: ios, core-location

In the **settings** > my app > **location**, user can choose between

```
 - never
 - While using the App
 - Always
```

but i would like to have only :

```
 - never
 - Always
```

i know that other app did like this, so how to remove the While using the App options ?

Comment: I hope this can't be done. I never allow apps to access my location in the background.

Comment: This functionality, to remove `While using` is only available for iOS 10. In the current iOS 11 beta you cannot remove this option

Comment: @Ollie : do you have some official doc about this ?

Comment: They discussed it in the 'What's New in Location Technologies' WWDC video this year: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/713/. You can jump to the specific part by searching the transcript for "So for iOS 11 we're asking all developers with Always requesting apps to additionally support the WhenInUse authorization mode."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding ONLY the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your Info.plist

[image]

Comment: thanks i will take a look, seam my framework don't permit to include only the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Comment: i can't verify it :( my framework don't permit it sad :( but before to go more deeply i will check what ollie say, that in ios 11 this not work anymore

Comment: Maybe it was just replaced by `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`. But I will check here too

Comment: raaah another key :( but i don't think they will add a new key

Comment: digging yet, as it affects us in the head. But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424092/location-services-not-working-in-ios-11

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424092/location-services-not-working-in-ios-11 ... so better to always add the 2 key :)

Comment: same remark at the same time ;) force is awaken ahah :)

Comment: lol... I said, this subject is dark. Always something to bother. However, it is not on docs yet... https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: Now its not possible , apple restrict to show always access can be show with while in use