# The app's Info.plist must contain an NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data

Tags: swift, maps, ios11

I am new to IOS. I am trying to use Maps to get user's current location. The tutorial i am following is for IOS 10.

I went through this post and did everything it said but still it doesn't work
[Location Services not working in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424092/location-services-not-working-in-ios-11)

Following is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {

    var locationManager=CLLocationManager()
    // @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        locationManager.delegate=self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
        let latitude=userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude=userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees=0.05
        let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees=0.05
        let span=MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:latDelta, longitudeDelta:lonDelta)
        let location=CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude)
        let region=MKCoordinateRegion(center:location,span:span)
        self.mapView.setRegion(region,animated:true)

    }



}
```

I have added following in my info.plist file

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Program requires GPS to track cars and job orders</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Program requires GPS to track cars and job orders</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Program requires GPS to track cars and job orders</string>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". That's not a useful description. What is the exact issue with the code you posted?

Comment: I am not able to get user's current location. It doesn't even give me the permission dialog?

Comment: Are you working in the simulator or a real device? If a simulator (and provided GPS works there), try resetting it and then re-installing it. If a device, try deleting the app and re-installing it.

Comment: @dfd How to reset GPS in simulator

Comment: No. The Simulator. *"Hardware|Erase all Content and Settings"*. (My memory says it changed in Xcode 9. Beware!) More importantly... please, be **100% sure** that the GPS works in the simulator! (I honestly do not know. I know the camera doesn't. So why - IMHO - should the GPS?) The behavior you've described can be... both.

Comment: @dfd GPS does work in simulator, but in the menu bar you need to go to Debug -> Location -> And then either do a custom or predefined.

Comment: An ios project has several info.plist files, Make sure you're editing the correct one!

Answer (score 23):

If you are using the simulator, make sure you have a location chosen.
Select the simulator, in the menu bar you need to go to Debug -> Location -> And then either do a custom or predefined.

If you've done that, try the below.

Rather than manually entering that text in the info.plist, I would just open it with the default editor.

Click the plus button that is shown in the blue highlighted area ( you can really select any of them) This will add a new row.
[image]

Second, Type in Privacy - Location When ... Select the one that applies to you.
[image]

After you have the left side filled out, double tap the right side and enter the text you want shown to the user.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There should be three descriptions in info.plst.

[image: Info.plst]