# Current App does not have Location permissions, requesting permissions?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I used Xamarin Forms 3.3 for my app. When debug app test on iOS.

My logs file always has 2 lines:

`2019-01-13 21:19:59.575 Marine.Mobile.iOS[2751:542039] Currently does not have Location permissions, requesting permissions`

`2019-01-13 21:19:59.599 Marine.Mobile.iOS[2751:542039] This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain both “NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription” and “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription” keys with string values explaining to the user how the app uses this data`

I set in file `Info.plist` as [Location Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424092/location-services-not-working-in-ios-11):

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Marine requires GPS to track cars and job orders</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Marine requires GPS to track cars and job orders</string>
```

but can't run or debug program.

It can't display name of project [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEV3i.png)

And Error: [Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKptF.png)

I try only use below code in file `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Marine requires GPS to track cars and job orders</string>
```

=> Project can run debug.

Then, I try don't use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and replace it with `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, but program can't debug.

`<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Marine requires GPS to track cars and job orders</string>`

=> Why code can't add it in file `Info.plist`:

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: Delete the app from the emulator/device and retry delaying/debugging (changes to the info.plist, app icons, etc... with debug builds tend to require a scratch re-installed).

Comment: What is the version of your device's system? The ones before and after iOS10.0 are different.

Comment: You should paste your entire Info.plist content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Double tap in YourProject.iOS. Choose Configuration and Add new Configuration.