# iOS App not showing location permission in app settings

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm developing an app for iOS and Android using Xamarin where I need to use the user's location but the location permission isn't displaying on within the app settings.

I've added:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description of usage</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description of usage</string>
```

to my Info.plist file but it isn't showing the location settings in my app settings.

I've also added the permissions for Media Library and Camera and they're showing perfectly fine so I'm not sure why location is any different.

Per some advice online I've also tried re-installing the app and rebooting the device, but neither have changed what I'm seeing.

I'm testing this on iOS 12.3.1.

Thanks

Comment: did you request location in app code?

Comment: yes, I've made the request for the permission but it doesn't pop up on screen. Camera and Media Library do as expected.

Comment: Are you experiencing this in the simulator or any other device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is I'm just a moron.

I was using the Permissions Plugin and setting NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription but using PermissionsPlugin I was only checking Location, not LocationAlways and LocationWhenInUse.

Thanks to anyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map#ios):

To access location services on iOS, you must set the following keys in Info.plist:

- iOS 11

  [NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26) – for using location services when the app is in use
  [NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization?language=objc) – for using location services at all times
- iOS 10 and earlier

  [NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26) – for using location services when the app is in use
  [NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18) – for using location services at all times

To support iOS 11 and earlier, you can include all three keys: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`, and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

See this thread for more information: [location-services-not-working-in-ios-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424092/location-services-not-working-in-ios-11)

Answer (score 0):

do not fight, just use this plug in

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/issues/93